# Manage angularjs controller init with karma tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Ive seen such questions and they all say 'extract logic out into a service and mock the service'. Simple, except i have as much as possible.

So when the controller inits i have a call to `$scope.getWidgets()` this method calls `widgetService` to get a list of widgets for the user, it will then display a toast notification using `notifyService`. Should `widgetService` reject its promise or the user have no widgets a call to `notifyService` is made. This is all done when the controller inits.

```
$scope.getWidgets = function () {
    widgetService.getWidgets()
        .then(function (widgets) {
            if (widgets.length === 0) {
                notifyService.notify('no widgets');
            }

            $scope.widgets = widgets;
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            notifyService.notify('oh noes');
        });
}

//called at bottom of controller
$scope.getWidgets();
```

Now all my tests so for have not had need to run any digest cycles, run running promises etc. The method im trying to test calls a service to save a widget. Should it succeed or fail it will again call `notifyService` to send a notification to the user. I'm testing that the notification is triggered using karma's `spyOn` and also testing some flags are set correctly. There's no real logic, thats done in the service.

```
$scope.saveWidget = function (widget) {
    widgetService.saveWidget(widget)
        .then(function () {
            notifyService.notify('all dandy');
            //set some scope flags, no logic
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            notifyService.notify('oh noes');
            //set some more scope flags, no logic
        });
}
```

So now i have have to run the digest cycle to trigger my promises. The Trouble is my mock for `widgetService.getWidgets()` returns a promise. So when i run the digest first it resolves the promise registered in my init, which calls the notify service, which activates my spyon, concluding my test with false data.

Here are my tests, (please forgive the big code block, ive tried to strip it down as much as possible).

```
describe('tests', function () {
    var scope, controlelr, _mockWidgetService, _mockNotifyService;

    beforeEach(function () {
        //Init the service mocks, angular.noop for methods etc
        _mockWidgetService = init();
        _mockNotifyService = init();
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        //Regisetr hooks to pull in my mocked services
        angular.mock.module('myModule');

        angular.mock.module(function($provide) {
            $provide.value('widgetService', _mockWidgetService);
            $provide.value('notifyService', _mockNotifyService);
        })
    });

    angular.mock.inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, widgetService, notifyService) {
        //create scope and inject services to create controller
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        //Trouble is $scope.getWidgets() is called now.
        controller = $controller('testController', {
            $scope: scope,
            widgetService: widgetService,
            notifyService: notifyService
        });
    });

    describe('getWidgets', function() {
        it('myTest', function () {
            //I cannow manipulate mock services moreso if needed just for this test
            spyOn(_mockNotifyService, 'notfy');

            //Call save widget
            scope.saveWidget();

            scope.$digest();

            expect(_mockNotifyService.notify).toHaveBeenCalledWith(//values);
        });
    });
});
```

So as you can see im struggling, i could mock all the mocks required for the init code, but id rather only mock the services i need for that test. Plus i don't like the idea of the init code running every single test potentially causing false errors (it has its own tests).

Any advise or solutions to such use cases would greatly appreciated.

Comment: this unit test is IMO completely pointless. You need to unit test your service, but in your controller there is no logic so there is nothing to unit test.

Comment: @webduvet Ok maybe this example was not the best. My controller does have small bits of logic, such as calling different services depending on flags, showing the user different toast notifications etc. These small bits of logic i believe have value in being tested. As i stated my services are fully tested.

Comment: such a behaviours should be covered in e2e tests not unit tests. Your user certainly will not set the flags in chrome console. Should I be strict I would say no logic at all is desired in controller.

Comment: @webduvet i will bear that in mind next time. Thanks for your advise. Edit: can you explain why exactly, your user won't be changing a promise chain in a service.

Comment: no need to be defensive. My point was that simulating user action by modifying scope properties in test and then trigger some mocked services method which in turn returns a mocked promise in which another mocked service is called does not make any sense to me. It only ads tight coupling to your actual service implementation. Let's say If you change your service contract and do not change the mocks in controller's tests your unit tests will still pass, but your app will not work.

Comment: @webduvet Sorry, i was not meaning to sound defensive, just trying to understand :) i think there may be confusion, i'm not trying to test a chain of mocked services, i understand the issues there. But moreover testing that when a service responds with data the controller handles that data correctly, either by calling another service which i spyOn as assert it was called or setting flags etc. Its not a nested mess or a billion if else's but its also not a single `if(isTrue){}` either. I appreciate your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a potential solution that seems to work. I'm not entirely sure its best practice so if there are better options id be very grateful to hear them.

Essentially instead of mocking up my `widgetService.getWidgets` with a resolved promise before every test i mock it up with a deferred promise which never resolves. Idea being for tests that do not require it the init code will never run as the promise never resolves.

Tests that do require it to run just overwrite the mock and have `widgetService.getWidgets` return what is required.

That did mean some small changes, the controller had to be instantiated manually for each test (using beforeEach where available) instead of at the top of the very first describe).